# Why isn't the latest version installed from the PPA as advertised?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt

I have the ethereum PPAs enabled

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum-dev/ubuntu
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum-qt/ubuntu
```

I have run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Etherum appears to have been installed correctly but at a lower version than it should.

```
#> geth version
Version: 1.1.3
```

There are no conflicting versions.

```
#>whereis geth
geth: /usr/bin/geth
```

If I navigate to http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum-dev/ubuntu/pool/main/e/ethereum/ then there is this, which looks correct

```
geth_1.5.0+964SNAPSHOT20160425104610trusty-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

**So why isn't this version (1.5) installed?**

The version of geth in [the non-dev PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu/pool/main/e/ethereum/) is 1.3, which is also higher than what is installed.

Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out muon-discover is misleading me. The repositories were checked but not actually active. Here's what it looked like.

[image]

But `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` revealed the truth of the matter.

Comment: The bottom 2 do look checked... so how did you discover they're not & fix it?